# How to use PanResponder in functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The official documentation and all the tutorials I found use PanResponder as a part of React Classes, but is there a way we can use it with functional components and hooks?
I tried doing it as follows but it doesn't seem to work:-

```
const App = props => {
  const position = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue({x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy});
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {},
    }),
  ).current;

...

<Animated.View
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[
              {transform: position.getTranslateTransform()},
              styles.appStyles,
            ]}>
...
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25360#issuecomment-505241400

useMemo avoids recreating the PanResponder on every rerendering

then your code should look like this

```
const App = props => {
  const position = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const panResponder = React.useMemo(() => PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue({x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy});
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {},
    }), []);

...

<Animated.View
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[
              {transform: position.getTranslateTransform()},
              styles.appStyles,
            ]}>
...
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: This is wrong. WIth use memo, your pan handlers will get there forever if you create the panResponder again. They will then block the InteractionManager.

Comment: @DiogoAleixo Do you have other solution for this ?

Comment: See https://snack.expo.dev/@chxryan/panresponder-caching-issue for an example of using `useMemo` and the issue got resolved. I don't see any objections on using `useMemo` in the RN doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

@DiogoAleixo Could you elaborate a bit more on your comment with blocking the InteractionManager?

Answer (score 4):

The official doc suggests using `useRef()`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder

Below is the copied example from the official documentation

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The gesture has started. Show visual feedback so the user knows
        // what is happening!
        // gestureState.d{x,y} will be set to zero now
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The most recent move distance is gestureState.move{X,Y}
        // The accumulated gesture distance since becoming responder is
        // gestureState.d{x,y}
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) =>
        true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // The user has released all touches while this view is the
        // responder. This typically means a gesture has succeeded
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Another component has become the responder, so this gesture
        // should be cancelled
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        // Returns whether this component should block native components from becoming the JS
        // responder. Returns true by default. Is currently only supported on android.
        return true;
      }
    })
  ).current;

  return <View {...panResponder.panHandlers} />;
};
```

Comment: useRef is correct, this should be the accepted answer